# Parsing xml from a website Java

Tags: java

How can I parse xml from website using Java ?

For example this one http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML

Anyone knows how is it done?

Comment: Use an xml parser. Google or SO search is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/) the Oracle Java/XML tutorial. That will give you an overview of the most common XML APIs for Java, together with their pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

There are several XML libraries which you can use for this. [jdom](http://jdom.org) has always worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML parser](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx04paj.htm),there are so many resources on the web.

Additionally read those.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=62782

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest option is to use "[xStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html)". All you need is to define a "Rates/Rate" POJO classes with appropriate member attributes and use something like below:

```
 Rates rates = (Rates) xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

Use [two minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/). Powerful and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is simple enough to parse manually using the DOM or SAX API, but I'd still suggest using an XML serialization API such as [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html), or [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) instead because writing your own XML serialization/deserialization code is a drag.

Note that the XStream FAQ erroneously claims that you must use generated classes with JAXB:

> *How does XStream compare to JAXB (Java API for XML Binding)?*
>
> JAXB is a Java binding tool. It generates Java code from a schema and
>   you are able to transform from those classes into XML matching the
>   processed schema and back. Note, that you cannot use your own objects,
>   you have to use what is generated.

It seems this was true was true at one time, but JAXB 2.0 no longer requires you to use Java classes generated from a schema.

If you go this route, be sure to check out the side-by-side comparisons of the serialization/marshalling APIs I've mentioned:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html